# Precede Bootstrap lines of code with $

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my code to be preceded with a '$' like a command line prompt but make that '$' not part of the highlightable text.

## index.html

```
<pre class="pre-scrollable">  
    <span class="com">git clone https://github.com/vccabral/vagrant-django-template-1.git</span>  
    <span class="com">cd vagrant-django-template-1</span>  
    <span class="com">vagrant up</span>  
    <span class="com">vagrant ssh</span>  
    <span class="com">python -c "import this"</span>  
</pre>
```

Comment: I added a blinking cursor (I'm committed to keeping the blink tag relevant :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a [CSS 2.1](http://jsfiddle.net/8YmcN/) (I didn't know it existed back then) way to do this ([demo](http://cssdesk.com/wvLAw)):

```
.com::before {
  content: "$";
  display: inline;
}
```

Copy and Past it and you should not see the `$`.  Of course this uses some CSS that may not be supported by the browsers you are targeting.  This is called the [`content`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html) declaration or CSS Generated Content.  [Here is a list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) of it's support.

Also if you make a slight change to your html you can add a blinking cursor ;)

```
<pre class="pre-scrollable">  
    <span class="com">git clone https://github.com/vccabral/vagrant-django-template-1.git</span>  
    <span class="com">cd vagrant-django-template-1</span>  
    <span class="com">vagrant up</span>  
    <span class="com">vagrant ssh</span>  
    <span class="com last">python -c "import this"</span>  
</pre>

.com::before {
    content: "$";
    display: inline;
}

.com.last::after {
    content: "_";
    display: inline;
    text-decoration:blink;
}
```

Comment: thanks. that is exactly what i wanted. it works perfectly. http://www.boxes.vg/manifest/1/